# How to improve render html speed

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rendering, render

My rails app works fine, but is too slow in rendering from DB. Example: "Completed in 4027ms (View: 3758, DB: 87)". Rails 2.3.8. How can I improve the html render speed in rails apps?

**USING: action.html.erb**

Comment: You'll have to give more information such as: what type of data are you rendering? do you have complex loops in your erb?

Comment: [profiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming))?

Comment: show the code in your view, sounds like you could be iterating and loading `has_many` or `belongs_to` attributes in your view resulting in lots of queries

Comment: _Try to use index.php!_ Show your code :)

Comment: Please show the controller and view code. Either you do some complicated calculations (very!), some very inefficient looping, some blocking resource, ... ???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am sure:

1. You are making queries inside your view
2. You are rendering a lot of partial
3. You are nesting rendering partials
4. You are using expensive Ruby operations in your views (sorting, selecting, maping)
5. You are nesting expensive operations (n2, n4... code)

Examples, to explain it:

1. @my_objects = MyObject.where(:foo => :bar).all
2. @my_objects.each{ |object| render object }
3. @my_objects.each{ |object| render object }
   _object.html.erb
   object.children.each{ |child| render child }
4. @my_objects.sort_by{ |a,b| a.id <=> b.id }
5. @my_objects.sort_by{ |a,b| a.map(&:id).last.name <=> b.map(&:id).last.name }

Comment: So why minuses, guys? :)

Comment: Actually, if in controller i add @market = Market.find(:all), and in view i add: @market.category = it means 'query inside your view', right?

Comment: Absolutley. You should use `Eager loading` here. [Eager loading screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/22-eager-loading)

Comment: Becarefull if you are using fragment caching in your view, then its not good enough to force the query to be executed inside the controller. Because we don't want to query the database if we cache something.

Comment: I agree with not making queries in the view, but I'm certain that queries in the view are still counted as part of the overall "DB" time for the request. In the example log entry, this could only add (up to) 87ms to the total 3758ms view rendering time.

Answer (score 2):

1/ Probably you are making lots of things in your view (ordering or something). You could ask MySQL to do more job.

2/ You can use rails caching (actions, fragments ...)